# How to capture the body of a request that was stubbed with Wiremock

Tags: java, spring-boot, mocking, wiremock, stubbing

Is there a way to capture the body of a post request that was stubbed with wiremock? I'm looking for something similar to Mockito's `ArgumentCaptor`.

I have the following stub:

```
stubFor(post(urlPathEqualTo(getUploadEndpoint())).willReturn(().withStatus(HttpStatus.OK.value())));
```

I want to be able to see how the actual request was performed, get its body and assert it.

I have tried by using `.withRequestBody(equalToXml(...))` in the stub, since the body is the String representation of an XML. This does not work for me, because `equalToXml` is too strict, not allowing free text without surrounding tags for example.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I managed to find a solution by doing this:
I attributed a UUID to the stub

```
stubFor(post(urlPathEqualTo(getUploadEndpoint())).willReturn(aResponse().withStatus(HttpStatus.OK.value()))).withId(java.util.UUID.fromString(UUID)));
```

and I gathered all serve events happening on this particular endpoint

```
List<ServeEvent> allServeEvents = getAllServeEvents(ServeEventQuery.forStubMapping(java.util.UUID.fromString(UUID)));
// this list should contain one stub only
assertThat(allServeEvents).hasSize(1);
ServeEvent request = allServeEvents.get(0);
String body = request .getRequest().getBodyAsString();
```

Then I used XMLUnit to assert this body. Seems to do the job, but I'm open to any other solutions if available.

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively, you can use the API to find requests that match a predicate:

```java
import static com.github.tomakehurst.wiremock.client.WireMock.*;

List<LoggedRequest> requests = findAll(
    postRequestedFor(urlEqualTo(getUploadEndpoint()))
        .withRequestBody(matchingXPath("your xpath here"))
);
```

Then you can assert whatever you want about the matched requests.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the API to [verify that a request was made with the expected body](https://wiremock.org/docs/verifying/).

```java
import static com.github.tomakehurst.wiremock.client.WireMock.*

verify(
    postRequestedFor(urlEqualTo(getUploadEndpoint()))
        .withRequestBody(matchingXPath("your xpath here"))
);
```

See [WireMock / Request Matching / XPath](https://wiremock.org/docs/request-matching/#:%7E:text=CHILD_NODELIST_LENGTH%20CHILD_LOOKUP%20ATTR_NAME_LOOKUP-,XPath,-Deems%20a%20match) for examples of XPath matching.

Comment: This works, but did not fit my case since my XML was large and couldn't write all the paths in `matchingXPath` function. But it's a good answer, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I tried like below

```
return stubFor(post(uri)
                .withHeader("Content-Type", equalTo("application/json"))
                .withHeader("Accept", equalTo("application/json"))
                .withRequestBody(WireMock.equalToJson(requestPayload))
                .willReturn(WireMock.aResponse()
                        .withStatus(HttpStatus.OK.value())
                        .withHeader("Content-Type", MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
                        .withBody(response))).toString();
```